# DBLINK in Postgres between 2 Databases always gives Syntax error

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-9.3, dblink

I have `2` databases and I'm trying to JOIN 2 tables (1 from each)

Both tables have the property `userId` of type `character varying(40)` , and the script as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM public.users tb1
INNER JOIN ((SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=db_employees','SELECT id FROM employees')) AS tb2(userId character varying(40)))
on tb1.userId = tb2.userId
where "tb1"."userId" = 'gfgfg-43436-htrewd-1111'
```

Which produces:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "character"
LINE 2: ...r_users','SELECT id FROM results')) AS tb2(userId character ...
                                                             ^
```

What's wrong with the script of the JOIN ?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify a data type in an alias.

If you need to cast the data type, do that in the `SELECT` list:

```
(SELECT CAST(userid AS text)
 FROM dblink(
         'dbname=db_employees',
         'SELECT id FROM employees'
      ) AS x(userid)
) AS tb2(userid)
```